# Does R use inexact matching when subsetting dataframe rows using square bracket notation?

Tags: r, subset

Given a simple data frame:

```r
df <-
  structure(
    list(
      lowercase = c("j", "t", "u"),
      uppercase = c("J", "T", "U")
    ),
    row.names = c("10", "20", "21"),
    class = "data.frame"
  )
```

```
> df
   lowercase uppercase
10         j         J
20         t         T
21         u         U
```

Selecting using row names that do not exist usually returns a data frame of `NA`s:

```
> df["2",]
   lowercase uppercase
NA      <NA>      <NA>
```

... but not always:

```
> df["1",]
   lowercase uppercase
10         j         J
```

*Why does subsetting a data frame sometimes return rows for which there is no (exact) matching row.name?*

I've tried this on both linux (CentOS) and MacOS, using R versions `3.1.2`, `3.2.3`, `3.6.0`, and `4.0.3` with the same results.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   ~/tools/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: ~/tools/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_CA.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_CA.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_CA.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_CA.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_CA.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.2
```

Comment: Occurs in `4.0.4` also. Testing a few other cases, I see row.name  `"01"` will match `df["0",]`.

Comment: I never saw that. Perhaps "2" is not matched because there are two row names starting with "2"?

Comment: I've just had a much closer read of ?Extract.data.frame and it looks like R matching incomplete row names (character) is a feature?

`swiss["Cou",]`

Comment: Multiple matches seems to be the answer. If you run `rownames(df)[3] <- "31"`, then `df["2", ]` will return the second row.

Answer (score 1):

After a much closer reading of the `Extract.data.frame` manual page, I see that the square bracket notation will partially match row names.

The example given in the manual is:

```r
> sw <- swiss[1:5, 1:4]

> sw
             Fertility Agriculture Examination Education
Courtelary        80.2        17.0          15        12
Delemont          83.1        45.1           6         9
Franches-Mnt      92.5        39.7           5         5
Moutier           85.8        36.5          12         7
Neuveville        76.9        43.5          17        15

> sw["C",]
           Fertility Agriculture Examination Education
Courtelary      80.2          17          15        12
```

The recommended solution is to use `match`:

```r
> sw[match("C", row.names(sw)), ] 
   Fertility Agriculture Examination Education
NA        NA          NA          NA        NA
```

Bringing this answer back to question posed above, the correct approach would be:

```r
df[match("1", row.names(df)), ]
```